# Difference between "__method__" and "method"

Tags: python, methods

What is the difference between `__method__`, `method` and `_method__`?

Is there any or for some random reason people thought that `__doc__` should be right like that instead of `doc`. What makes a method more special than the other?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

- `__method`: private method.
- `__method__`: special Python method. They are named like this to prevent name collisions. [Check this page for a list of these special methods.](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ref/specialnames.html)
- `_method`: This is the recommended naming convention for protected methods in the [Python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

From the style guide:

> - `_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator.  E.g. `from M
>       import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.
> - `single_trailing_underscore_`: used by convention to avoid conflicts with
>       Python keyword, e.g.
>
>   ```
>   Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')
>   ```
> - `__double_leading_underscore`: when naming a class attribute, invokes name
>       mangling (inside class `FooBar`, __boo becomes `_FooBar__boo`; see below).
> - `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or
>       attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces.  E.g. `__init__`,
>      `__import__` or `__file__`.  Never invent such names; only use them
>       as documented.

Comment: __method isn't really private, it's mangled with the class name but it still can be accessed normally. +1 though.

Comment: -1. because __x is not private in the OOP-sense, and that's not the point of it. The point is to avoid two classes using the same attribute by mistake. It's namespace handing, rather than private/protected.

Answer (score 23):

- `method` is just a normal method
- `_method` should not be called unless you know what you are doing, which normally means that you have written the method yourself.
- `__method` the 2 underscores are used to prevent name mangeling. Attributes or methods like this are accessible over `instance._ClassName__method`. Although a lot of people call this "private" it is *not*.  You should never use this to prevent someone from accessing this method, use `_method` instead.
- `__method__` is used for special methods which modify the behavior of the instance. Do not name your own methods like this.

Answer (score 4):

These are all conventions, so they are not enforced in anyway. Still, you can normally expect:

```
__somename__
```

Something defined in the python language specification itself. Don't use this in your own naming.

```
_somename
```

This is normally supposed to be called via some different mechanism rather than directly. Similar to declaring something private in most other languages, but not enforced in any way.

```
__somename
```

This is *really* not supposed to be called directly, and is mangled internally to stop you doing so accidently. If you really need to call it for some reason, check the documentation to find out how.

Any of the above can apply equally to function, variable or class names.

Answer (score 1):

These methods were named as such to reduce the possibility of naming collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Methods prefaced and prefixed with the double underscore are generally so marked to indicate that they are part of the Python language specification.

Answer (score 0):

Some methods with a double underscore prefix and suffix are special. For example, `__init__` is called whenever an instance of that class is created, and `__str__` is called when the object is to be printed. Basically, they can be called in special ways. You can use them like any other method, or you can invoke them through the special way associated to them.

I don't know about double-underscore global functions (not belonging to any class), but I think there aren't any.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern of `__name__` indicate "magic" methods. These are called by various functions like

```
str(x) -> x.__str__()
repr(x) -> x.__repr__()
x[0] -> x.__getitem__(0)
etc
```

A single underscore prefix is to indicate a private attribute, and is only followed through convention.

a double underscore prefix initiates name-mangling, where the attribute named __attr is changed to __Class_attr upon instantiation.

The pattern you have of _method__ isn't really used for anything.