# Is it a bad programing practice to put a function inside a class method?

Tags: python, oop

I'm looking at a case like this:

```
def parse_item(self, response):

    item = MetrocItem()

    def ver(string):
        if string:
            return string
        else:
            return 'null'

    item['latitude'] = ver(response.xpath('//input[@id="latitude"]/@value').extract_first())
```

It works, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you define the function outside of the method (indeed even outside the class)? None of its local variables depend on anything in the current scope.

Comment: This is bad practice since the function is defined again on every call of the method. You should put it anywhere else, like in to the namespace of the module or into a `helpers.py`, or similar.

Comment: It is debatable, but it is good practice to keep the scope of variables and functions as narrow as possible.

Comment: @KlausD. Do you have any reference to back up that statement? I would think that the function is defined once and a name is bound to it everytime the method is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Graipher mentioned in the comments, this is certainly valid in some cases, but in your particular case, it is unnecessary. If your function depends on a local variable, then you're returning a *closure* that needs to be reconstructed every time you call the method. But in your case, the function is going to behave the same way every time you call the method, so it would make more sense to define it globally as a private method, or even as a lambda in your case.

```
ver = lambda x: x if x else 'null'
```

But the preferred approach would be to simply define it globally and start the name with an underscore to make the intention clear.

```
def _ver(string):
    ...
```

Comment: or just
`x = response.xpath('//input[@id="latitude"]/@value').extract_first()` and then
`item['latitude'] = x if x else "null"` oh this is @Niklas answer actually...

Comment: It's not going to get reconstructed every time. Code objects will be created for every function, including local functions and reused for every invocation. So in a sense, it's already constructed, just a new reference to that code is created in every call.

Comment: Ok my code was a bit longer though:    but I defined the function outside the class and used it inside the method.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of that function completely:

```
string = response.xpath('//input[@id="latitude"]/@value').extract_first()
item['latitude'] = string if string else 'null'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are use cases for having a local function - either in a class method or other method, say if you want a *closure* capturing something local.

In you case you want something like a colasecing null:

e.g.

```
>>> s = None
>>> s or "None"
'None'
```

So, you can use

```
item['latitude'] = response.xpath('//input[@id="latitude"]@value').extract_first() or "null"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not bad practice, but here's an alternative.

Since this small function doesn't depend on anything in `parse_item` and you might want it to be constructed only once, for performance, you could do this:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    ...

def _ver(string):
    ...

parse_item.ver = _ver
del _ver
```

and refer to it inside `parse_item` as `parse_item.ver` instead of just `ver`. This avoids cluttering the global namespace, even with an underscored method that Python partially hides for you.

I would have recommended the lambda expression as another alternative, but Silvio got to it first.

Also, the comments that it could be a global function, visible to all, only makes sense if there's any chance it might be used anywhere else.

Also also, you can eliminate this example completely, as doctorlove and Niklas have suggested, but I assume that you mean this as an example of more complex cases.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `parse_item` is a method inside your class. Then you can use Python's "private" methods to make your code more readable and cleaner.
Check how to write [Python "private" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935378/difference-between-method-and-method?noredirect=1&lq=1) and then check [why it's not actually a private method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name?noredirect=1&lq=1). ;)